# How to load a picture in a division into another division from its current division?

Tags: html, events, iframe, load, division

here is my explaination...

i want to load an image in division called div1.. and the same time, i want it to load to another division called div2.. the code must be from the div1..

```
<div class="div1">
    <p> 
        <iframe width="100px" height="55px" src="EC.php" href="EC.php" target="two"></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <p> 
        <iframe width="100px" height="55px" name="two"></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
```

the EC.php page contains the command of the image that i want to load.. any idea?

Comment: You missed to close your `<div class = "div1">`, which is also the same for your second div.

Comment: haha.. </div> is just a typo.. i have corrected it.. thanx, btw..

Comment: Does it is wrong if you copy/paste the `iframe` code from the `div1` to implement it into the `div2` ?

Comment: no.. it is not wrong..i can do that.. but, i just need one division to control other division..